Complex Json mapping with Azure data factory
I have to map an output Json format of an API that contains multiple collections, nested arrays...
I well receive the Json file, then i use the activity copy to transform Json to Parquet file, in the mapping settings, i manually create the complex mapping and i get the data, it works fine but...
The issue is that the Cross join is not applied good, means give me for the nested array (ChildRows) only the first index.

so in the above example will give me only first values of rowuid_Child_value1 of ChildRows (array) and not the values of the second one (rowuid_Child_value2)...
this is the mapping in adf

I have tried also with advanced editor, dynamics mapping but not the expected result.
Do you have any advice please or same situations in ADF? i can't use the DataFlow as we don't have it our project with adf so this is not an option.
Thank you for helping...

You can achieve your requirement by following below procedure:
Go to Mapping of copy activity Enable Advanced editor and enter $['Rows'][0]['ChildRows'] Collection reference as shown below:

Then mapping will set as below:

With above mapping the Json data will modify as shown below:



Rows[0]['RowUID']
FormNumber
IncidentDate
IncidentSummary
RecoveryRequired
BusinessEntity
Classification
Rows[0]['EntityName']
Rows[0]['ParentRowUID']
Item
LeftRowUID
Rows[0]['ChildRows'][0]['RowUID']
Ordinal
Type
Rows[0]['ChildRows'][0]['ParentRowUID']
IsReportableEnvDamage
Rows[0]['ChildRows'][0]['EntityName']
Consequence
Code
Reportable




rowuid_value
xxx
date
data
1
data
data
xxx
rowuid_value
xxx
rowuid_value
rowuid_Child_value1
0
xxx
xxx
0
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx


rowuid_value
xxx
date
data
1
data
data
xxx
rowuid_value
xxx
rowuid_value
rowuid_Child_value2
0
xxx
rowuid_value
1
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx



Here is the pipeline Json for your reference:
{
    "name": "pipeline2",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Copy data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "JsonSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "JsonReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                            "quoteAllText": true,
                            "fileExtension": ".txt"
                        }
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "mappings": [
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "$['Rows'][0]['RowUID']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Rows'][0]['RowUID"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "$['Rows'][0]['FormNumber']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "FormNumber"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "$['Rows'][0]['IncidentDate']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "IncidentDate"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "$['Rows'][0]['IncidentSummary']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "IncidentSummary"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "$['Rows'][0]['RecoveryRequired']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "RecoveryRequired"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "$['Rows'][0]['BusinessEntity']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "BusinessEntity"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "$['Rows'][0]['Classification']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Classification"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "$['Rows'][0]['EntityName']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Rows'][0]['EntityName"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "$['Rows'][0]['ParentRowUID']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Rows'][0]['ParentRowUID"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "$['Rows'][0]['Item']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Item"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "['LeftRowUID']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "LeftRowUID"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "['RowUID']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Rows'][0]['ChildRows'][0]['RowUID"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "['Ordinal']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Ordinal"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "['Type']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Type"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "['ParentRowUID']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Rows'][0]['ChildRows'][0]['ParentRowUID"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "['IsReportableEnvDamage']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "IsReportableEnvDamage"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "['EntityName']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Rows'][0]['ChildRows'][0]['EntityName"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "['Consequence']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Consequence"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "['Code']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Code"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "['Reportable']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Reportable"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "collectionReference": "$['Rows'][0]['ChildRows']",
                        "mapComplexValuesToString": false
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "Json2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}


it doesn`t work, it gives only 1 records not all and this because of the index 0 maybe that u specify... not sure if you are using copy activity with Json file as source, and Parquet file as sink? thanks.

Ensure you have followed this mapping. I am using copy activity with Json file as source, and Parquet file as sink.

yes sure follow it, and as i said already tried with advanced editor before and doesn't work, it gives only 1 record if we did this mapping...

enter $['Rows'][0]['ChildRows'] for collection reference then you will get the output.

I had same kind of problem, was not able to solve it using the copy data activity. Had to pass the json to a stored procedure and map it to a SQL table in the SP.

@Kornelis Raise a new question with your requirement with details.
